# Css class getting added through php but without styles

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to validate forms through php and whenever an error occurs I want the input field to be bordered by red color. The class is getting added but styles arent showing. The style is getting cancelled. Any advice to tackle this??

Below is a screrenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.error_field
{
    color:red !important;   // Now this will override the default css and apply yours
}
```

Comment: However this will work but at the same time, he/she should need to know why its getting overriding.

Additionally, We should avoid using **!important** unless they are absolutely necessary .. http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/